# Visual Composer Render a Loop Correct

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, visual-composer, wordpress-shortcode

i'm adding an element to visual composer that Renders a Title and subpages from a parent with exact ID "127".
Every variable is rendering right but its been showed incorrectly.

This is my code
Last code: Feb 18 / 19 
Code updated: February 19 / 19

```
    <?php
// Create Shortcode parentlink
// Use the shortcode: [parentlink]

if( defined( 'WPB_VC_VERSION' ) ) {

function vc_parent_links($atts) {

  // Attributes
  $atts = shortcode_atts(
    array(
    'sublinks_title' => ''
  ),
    $atts, 'parentlink'
  );
  // Attributes in var
  $sublinks_title = $atts['sublinks_title'];

  // Output Code



$argsvar = array(
    'post_type'      => 'page',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_parent'    => '217',
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'orderby'        => 'menu_order'
 );

$output = "";

$output .= '<h2 style="line-height: 1.2em; text-align: left; letter-spacing:0px;" class="vc_custom_heading">'.$sublinks_title.'</h2>';

$output .= '<section>';

$output .= '<ul class="parent-page">';

ob_start();

$parloop = new WP_Query( $argsvar );

if ( $parloop->have_posts() ) {

      while ( $parloop->have_posts() ) { $parloop->the_post();

        $permanlink = print_r(the_permalink(), true);
        $thetitle = print_r(the_title(), true);

        $output .= '<li><a href="'. $permanlink .'">'. $thetitle .'</a></li>';

      }
}



$output .= '</ul>';

$output .= '</section>';

$output .= '<p>HOLAAAA</p>';



  return $output;

}

ob_end_clean();

add_shortcode( 'parentlink', 'vc_parent_links' );

// Create Submenu list from parent for VC
add_action( 'vc_before_init', 'vc_parent_links_map' );

function vc_parent_links_map() {
  vc_map( array(
    'name' => __( 'Parent Sublinks', 'textdomain' ),
    'description' => __( 'Loads Sublinks from Parent', '' ),
    'base' => 'parentlink',
    'class' => 'sublinks',
    'show_settings_on_create' => false,
    'category' => __( 'Menus', 'textdomain'),
    'icon'    => get_template_directory_uri() . '/includes/images/portfolio.svg',
    'params' => array(
      array(
        'type' => 'textfield',
        'class' => '',
        'group' => __("General"),
        'admin_label' => true,
        'heading' => __( 'Title For Sublinks', 'textdomain' ),
        'param_name' => 'sublinks_title',
        'value' => '',
        'description' => __( 'This will be the title for the Portfolios Files.', 'textdomain' )
      ),
    )
  ) );
}
}// If VC Exist
```

The thing is that the loop is been rendered outside the wrapper
Heres 2 images to show you the error
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIVDd.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEmZq.jpg

The VC_Map its working, shortcode is rendering, something is hapening with the loop, any advice would be great, thanks.

Edited:
Image with < li > Expanded!!
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vfd1V.jpg

Comment: Expand the li's and take another screenshot.. Also, you should initialize `$output = "";`

Comment: Edited, and the link for the screentshot is there, thanks for the time, I added the empty output didn't work. @Yuri

Comment: @RodrigoZuluaga have you tried with ob_start() and ob_get_clean() ?

Comment: Try debug by replacing in the loop `$output .= '<li>'.print_r($permanlink, true).' - '.print_r($thetitle, true).'</li>';`.. Looks like some unwanted character in permalink or title

Comment: @MohammadAshiqueAli Yes i've tried the ob_ in several ways without luck, if theres any chance using my code tell me where to put it actually would be great. Updating code of how it its right now!!

Comment: @Yuri thanks for your time, updated code of how you have it still the same.
Code updated on this post of how I have it right now.

Comment: You only have to add the `print_r()` in order to debug your code.. Run it and check the output..